# JavaScript Date field validation

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using below Regex to validate date fields. I need to validate `MM/DD/YYYY` and also need to validate leap year. In all cases the below Regex is working fine except that when I enter `YY`, If I give `MM/DD/YY` it takes it as valid date and saving in DB as 4 digits of year as 0000. If I enter `MM/DD/Y` it is  returns the validation message just as if I enter `MM/DD/YYY`. It only `MM/DD/YY` case it fails. Can someone help me on this how to validate not enter 2 digits for year?

```
Dt_RegEx = /^(?:(?:(?:0?[13578]|1[02])(\/|-|\.)31)\1|(?:(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])(\/|-|\.)(?:29|30)\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:0?2(\/|-|\.)29\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$/;
```

Comment: I'll upvote just because I am curious to see the answer.  I think it actually belongs in a codegolf challange: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DougCoburn How could this possibly be a code golf? I don't see any kind of rationale behind such comment

Comment: Have you tried just using `Date.Parse`?  If it succeeds, it's valid, if not, no.

Comment: @DougCoburn - That's what the star is for; it marks it as a favourite so you can find the question easily later on.

Comment: Because using regex to validate MM/DD/YYY but only if it really is a valid date seems more like a puzzle than the best practical approach.  I agree with @Flydog57 use Date.Parse or a library to validate the date, not regex.

Comment: ha!  There actually already is one (similar) on codegolf: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54555/validate-iso-8601-by-rx

Comment: This is all the Leap Years between 0000 - 9999 `(?:[0-9](?:[0-9](?:0[48]|[13579][26]|[2468][048]))|(?:(?:[02468][048]|[13579][26])00))` Given a span of years, a program spits out leap years for that range. This should get you started on that _February_ thing.

Comment: You should not try to make separate regex for each circumstances. Make a single regex `MM/DD/YYYY` that is valid for all the dates. This would cover all Feb 1-28's. Then, just add an alternation at the end for `Feb 29` that is just for the Leap Years. Like I said, there is free software that can generate leap years for a given range of years. Or, just tell me the range of years, and I'll post the leap year regex for you. Note that to be consistent, you have to use the same range of years for every thing (example 1600-2999).

Comment: Leap Year Regex for 1600-2999: `(?:1(?:[6-9](?:0[48]|[13579][26]|[2468][048]))|2(?:[0-9](?:0[48]|[13579][26]|[2468][048]))|(?:(?:16|2[048])00))`

Comment: Take more care in spelling *JavaScript*. http://javascriptisnotjava.com